Publish GTK+ Application with msys2 and mingw64
I want to publish my GTK+ application with mingw64. But although I copied the gdkpixbuf loaders in right place,  the application can't find gdkpixbuf loaders and My application look's worse. How can I fix this problem?
I am copied gdkpixbuf loaders in lib\gdk-pixbuf-2.0\2.10.0\loaders path but It wasn't working

Is your application open source? If so, can you tell me where to find it, so I can have a look?

You need to be more specific about your issue and tell us more about your current setup. How worse it is ? What are your expectation ? What is your toolchain ? etc.

We need to see the layout of your distribution.  Where you copied the loaders to.  Is the windows path set appropriately for your application?
